# gnuplot use installed Windows system fonts?

Tags: fonts, gnuplot

Two related questions:
First, **how can I use an installed font with path "C:\Windows\Fonts\cmmi9.otf" in my gnuplot script (OS:Windows)**? The font name is `BKM-cmmi9` and I try to use it in my script with `set label "{/BKM-cmmi9 k}"`, but it doesn't work.

The reason I want to use such font is related with my second question: **How to use the same font of LaTeX math environment for letters in gnuplot**? Letter `k` in my LaTeX math environment looks like this

[image]

And I try to used the font of (italic Times New Roman):`set label "{/Times-New-Roman:Italic k}"` and the result looks like this

[image]

It is close to the font of LaTeX math environment, but still with a little difference.
I find my desired font in "C:\Windows\Fonts\cmmi9.otf", so the problem will solved if I can directly use such font and return to the first question.

Comment: With gnuplot version 5 the selection of font styles was changed: `set label "{/Times-New-Roman:Italic k}"`

Comment: To add to @Christoph's comment, the filename is not what's relevant here, it's what that font says its name is. So use whatever the actual font family string is for `cmmi9.otf`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  where can I find the family string for the font file `cmmi9.otf`, since the string(`BKM-CMMI9`) showed in Control-Windows-Fonts doesn't work.

Comment: That's an odd question, but: double click the file, then look at what windows' font viewer says is the "Font name".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Maybe I miss something, I used the font name  which is `BKM-cmmi9` like this `set label "{/BKM-cmmi9 k}"` in gnuplot, but it seems the font is not recognized by the gnuplot and the result is not with the `BKM-cmmi9` font.

Comment: I find the same font named `LM Roman 10` and `set label "{/LM-Roman-10:Italic k}"` can show the letter `k` with the font I wanted.